# String to bytearray conversion

Tags: java, io

```
public static void main(String args[]){


        try{
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
            int i = fs.read();
            while(i != -1){
                System.out.println( i);
                i = fs.read();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

The test.txt file contains " Č " . The output is 196 140 . the UTF-16 value of Č is 268 . Can you please help me why the answer is 196 and 140

Comment: The "ASCII value" of anything by definition can't be greater than 255.

Comment: That is a unicode value

Comment: Č converts to hex `c4 8c` which is coincidentally `196 140` in decimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify a specific encoding, Java uses "UTF-8" character encoding as default.

The UTF-8 (hex) for Č is 0xC4 0x8C, which translates to decimal as 196 and 140 respectively. When using UTF-16 for encoding, Č is represented by hex value of 0x010C, which in conversion to decimal becomes 268.

Comment: If you don't specify a specific encoding, Java uses a *platform default* character encoding. But that doesn't matter, since the code is reading *bytes*, not characters, so encoding is not involved. It is the program that *created* the `test.txt` file, e.g. a text editor, that chose to write the file in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating `InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_16);`

Or provide some other suitable charset encoding value.

Comment: Sorry, for misleading, to get the value of 268, you should use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`